# Send arrayBuffer with body

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use the file reader api and send data to a server. I've so far found out that I can't use readAsBinaryString anymore (it's been deprecated) but instead have to use readAsArrayBuffer.

I also have to send a body with the request. So my initial request looked like this:

```
var binaryString= fileData; //populated earlier from readAsBinaryString()

var body = "";
body += ...
body += binaryString;

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;...");
xhr.send();
```

I can't seem to use this when doing an arrayBuffer. I've tried converting the arrayBuffer to a string but that's too memory intensive for large files. So my question is how do I send arrayBuffer data AND a body at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I needed to do.

Instead of sending the body I needed to create a new FormData() object and attach it that way.

So it would look like this:

```
var formDataSend = new FormData();

formDataSend.append("key", "value...");
...
formDataSend.append("file", fileData, "fileName.jpg"); //fileData populated earlier from readAsBinaryString()

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(formDataSend);
```